# How do I put a string into an array of "words" in C?

Tags: c, string, 64-bit

So I am making a small program and I wanted to ask how do I break a string into an array of words? I tried strtok but I what if there is a tab or something like that?

```
char *S = "This  is     a cool sentence";
char *words[];
words[0] = "This";
words[1] = "is";
// etc.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: define word "word" first, for example `I'm` - is it word or not? what about `area51`, after that you will be able to decide what characters are words and what are not

Comment: Show your code using `strtok`. No problems with tabs, a tab is just another character.

Comment: @IłyaBursov I think for the moment this is the OP's last problem.

Comment: @Jabberwocky i tried https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm but I don't seem to figure out how to break it into an array

Comment: Follow an online C course instead of using a very inefficient way to learn.

Comment: You can scan character-by-character, testing it for [`isspace`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isspace). That catches spaces, tabs, newlines, etc. It will take a little more work to pull out the characters that fail `isspace` and create an array of words.

Comment: Unrelated: `char *S` is pointing at the first `char` in an array of `char`s that you are not allowed to change, so you might just as well make it `const char *S`. It helps to avoid programming mistakes.

Comment: You might review this example in parsing using "strtok" [String Splitting](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/14213/how-to-play-with-strings-in-c/string-split).  Instead of printing out the parsed strings, you might be able to use "sprintf".

Comment: You might find [these course notes](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10h.html) useful.

Answer (score 1):

**`strtok`** works just fine even if there are tabs in between. Setting the delimiter(the second argument of **`strtok`**) to **space**(" ") ignores all consecutive spaces also. For further clarification refer to the below code.

**EDITED:** As [@Chris Dodd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16406/chris-dodd) has rightly mentioned, you should add `\t` to the delimiter `strtok(str, " \t")` to ignore tabs also.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {

   // Initialize str with a string with bunch of spaces and tabs in between
   char str[100] = "Hi!     This   is a      long        sentence.";


   // Get the first word
   char* word = strtok(str, " \t");

   printf("First word: %s", word); // prints `First word: Hi!`


   // Declare an array of string to store each word
   char * words[20];

   int count = 0;

   // Loop through the string to get rest of the words
   while (1) {
    
      word = strtok(NULL, " \t");

      if(!word) break; // breaks out of the loop, if no more word is left
      
      words[count] = word; // Store it in the array
      
      count++;
   }
   
   
   int index = 0;
   
   // Loop through words and print
   while(index < count) {
    
      // prints a comma after previous word and then the next word in a new line
      printf(",\n%s", words[index]);
      
      index++;
   }


   return 0;
}
```

**Output** (*note that there is no space printed between the words and commas*) **:**

```
First word: Hi!,
This,
is,
a,
long,
sentence.
```

Comment: To ignore tabs, include tab in the delimiter characters:  `strtok(str, " \t")`

Comment: @ChrisDodd, thatk you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly making no claims on efficiency/elegance, but this is a possible implementation to split words on all whitespace.  This only prints out the words, it does not save them off to an array or elsewhere, I'll leave that as an exercise to you:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void printOrSaveWord(char curWord[], size_t curWordIndex)
{
    curWord[curWordIndex] = '\0';
    if (curWordIndex > 0)
    {
        printf("%s\n", curWord);
    }
}

void separateWords(const char* sentence)
{
    char curWord[256] = { 0 };
    size_t curWordIndex = 0;

    for (size_t i=0; sentence[i]; i++)
    {
        // skip all white space
        if (isspace(sentence[i]))
        {
            // found a space, print out the word. This where you would
            // add it to an array or otherwise save it, I'll leave that
            // task to you
            printOrSaveWord(curWord, curWordIndex);

            // reset index
            curWordIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            curWord[curWordIndex++] = sentence[i];
        }
    }
    // catch the ending case
    printOrSaveWord(curWord, curWordIndex);
}
```

[Demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/zPG8PWq94)